# I'm getting error C2664 on some I/O code

Tags: c++, visual-c++, huffman-code

```
void BinaryTree::InitializeFromFile(string Filename){
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open(Filename, fstream::binary);
if(inFile.fail()){
    cout<<"Error in opening file "<<Filename;
    return;
}
 for(int i=0;i<=255;i++) Freq[i]=0;
  char c;
  inFile.get(c);
  while(!inFile.eof()){
    Freq[c] ++;
    inFile.get(c);
  }
}  



HuffmanTree.cpp(293) : error C2664: 'void std::basic_ifstream<_Elem,_Traits>::
open(const wchar_t *,std::ios_base::openmode,int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 
from 'std::string' to 'const wchar_t *'
1>    with
1>    [
1>        _Elem=char,
1>        _Traits=std::char_traits<char>
1>    ]
1>    No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this 
      conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Line 293 is `inFile.open(Filename, fstream::binary);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Filename.c_str()` instead - `open()` doesn't take a `std::string` as a parameter for the filename.

Answer (score 3):

use `Filename.c_str()` instead of `Filename` in the call of `ifstream::open`

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat perplexingly, `ifstream::open` takes a C-string, not a C++ `std::string`. Change the line to:

```
inFile.open(Filename.c_str(), fstream::binary);
```

I have no idea why the designers of the C++ standard library made this choice, but there you go.

Comment: Because in general the C++ standard library design is to not force users to use features they don't want to use, such as std::string.

Comment: Fair enough, but to not even provide an overload that accepts `std::string` still strikes me as a bit weird.

Answer (score 1):

The `ifstream` ctor expects a `const char *`. Use `Filename.c_str()`.